# Why doesnt an ember observer fire on arrays?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to listen to specific property on every element in an array and get a result from that. However, updates dont appear to happen properly.

```
var emptyEmberObjectClass = Ember.Object.extend({});
var container = Ember.Object.extend({
  data: Ember.A([
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:1}),
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:2}),
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:3})
  ]),
  computedData: Ember.computed('data.@each.yo', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    this.get('data').forEach(function(data){
      sum = sum + data.yo;
    });
    return sum;
  }),
  test: Ember.observer('computedData', function(){
    Ember.$('#a').html('woohoO!');
  })
}).create();
var existingItem = container.get('data');
existingItem.objectAt(0).set('yo', 50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stb0nr2y/1/

As you can see, the text field still says 'start' and doesnt get updated to 'woohoO!'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
var emptyEmberObjectClass = Ember.Object.extend({});
var container = Ember.Object.extend({
  data: Ember.A([
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:1}),
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:2}),
    emptyEmberObjectClass.create({yo:3})
  ]),
  computedData: Ember.computed('data.@each.yo', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    this.get('data').forEach(function(data){
      sum += data.get('yo');
    });
    return sum;
  }),
  testObs: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('computedData', function() {
    Ember.$('#a').html('woohoO! cd: `' + this.get('computedData') + '`');
  }))
}).create();

var existingItem = container.get('data');
var target = existingItem.objectAt(0);
target.set('yo', 50);

target.set('yo', 100);
```

Updates DOM correctly with:

> woohoO! cd: `55`

and then:

> woohoO! cd: `105`

Please note that I'm using Ember v1.13.10:

```
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.10/ember.min.js"></script>
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/stb0nr2y/3/)